# Display Multiple Data Rows Within Table Row

Tags: mysql

Thanks to an earlier example by **Vara Prasad** I have expanded on his 
initial example of using MySQL **GROUP_CONCAT** and have certainly learned a 
lot since.

The following MySQL is what I am currently using and is functioning - below 
is an example of the results which while close to the desired output below 
does not achieve the desired data display - It only displays the first 
**LOCATION** field. I feel that perhaps the MySQL syntax has become unwieldly:
(NOTE: Also in my example I have made the Name field highlight on mouseover and clickable to search the database by client **Name**)

NOTES:
PAX = Passengers.  TotalPAX = The total of Adult & Children passengers.  TTime = TransferTime.  LOCATION and DESTINATION can be different however their TRANSFER REF will be the same.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT *, SUM(PAX) AS TotalPAX, GROUP_CONCAT('<a 
href=', 'PrintTransfers.php?Search=',TransferRef,'>', '<div class=', 
'TABLE-ROW-SELECTED', '>', Name, ' | ', PAX, '</div></a>' SEPARATOR '<hr 
/>') AS PasName FROM Transfers WHERE Date = '$DateToday' AND Agency = 'BT-
TAXIS' GROUP BY TransferRef, TTime ASC, Agency ORDER BY ServiceType DESC, 
TTime ASC");
$Ref = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
  $ID              = $row['ID']; // Internal Use
  $TTime           = $row['TransferTime'];
  $Location        = $row['PasLocation'];  
  $Destination     = $row['Destination'];
  $Name            = $row['PasName'];
  $PAX             = $row['TotalPAX']; // Stored as eg 2.3 which represents 
  2 Adults + 3 Children
  $PASSENGERS      = explode(".", $PAX);
  // var_dump($PASSENGERS);
  $Adults          = $PASSENGERS[0];
  $Children        = $PASSENGERS[1];
  $PAX             = $Adults + $Children;
  $TransferRef     = strtoupper($row['TransferRef']);     

// ADD HIGHLIGHTS      
switch ($Status){
case "GREY":
  $StatusHighlight = "#CCCCCC";
break;

default:
  $StatusHighlight = "#FFFFFF";    
}

print "<tr>
  <td bgcolor='$StatusHighlight' style='font-size:12px; text-
  align:center;'>$Ref</td>
  <td bgcolor='$StatusHighlight' style='font-size:12px; text-
  align:center;'>$TTime</td>
  <td bgcolor='$StatusHighlight' style='font-size:12px; text-
  align:center;'>$Location</td>
  <td bgcolor='$StatusHighlight' style='font-size:12px; text-
  align:center;'>$Destination</td>      
  <td bgcolor='$StatusHighlight' style='white-space: nowrap; font-size:12px; 
  text-align:right;'>$Name</td>     
  <td bgcolor='$StatusHighlight' style='font-size:12px; text-
  align:center;'>$PAX</td>
  <td bgcolor='$StatusHighlight' style='font-size:12px; text-
  align:center;'>$TransferRef</td>
</tr>";
$Ref++; 
} // END WHILE
```

Current Output:
[image]

The table below is the desired result - Note how "T-TIME" and "TRANSFER 
REF" are grouped, but "LOCATION" and "DESTINATION" are not - **T-TIME** is 
also ORDERED ASC:

Desired Output:
[image]

Also the following MySQL does indeed order the results correctly but displays each entry as a complete row which is not required, and using "GROUP BY" does not achieve the required result:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Transfers WHERE Date = '$DateToday' 
AND Agency = 'BT-TAXIS' ORDER BY ServiceType DESC, TransferRef, TTime 
ASC");

**GROUP BY** and **GROUP_CONCAT** seem to have an adverse affect on the data output and is not very flexible so I am thinking perhaps I should be working more with PHP than with MySQL to achieve the desired output.
```

I have been through all similar examples on Stack and through Google several times, so my question is how to tackle sorting the data programatically with PHP and multiple MySQL calls if that is indeed the correct path to choose. Regards to all who might consider this issue.

Still working with this I have changed the MySQL query, added an array and now tried the following... There are no errors:

```
$GetName = "PasName";
$query = mysql_query("SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT('<a href=', 'SearchName.php?
Search=',ID,'>', Name, ' @ ', PAX, '</a>',  ' @ ', Location, ' @ ' SEPARATOR 
' | ') AS PasName FROM Transfers WHERE Date = '$DateToday' AND Agency = 'BT-
TAXIS' GROUP BY TransferRef, TTime ASC, Agency ORDER BY ServiceType DESC, 
TTime ASC");

$Ref = 1;   
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
   $ID     = $row['ID'];
   $TTime  = $row['TransferTime'];
   $Agency = $row['Agency'];
   $Name   = $row[$GetName];

if (strpos($Name, ' | ') !== false) // ADDED TO INDICATE MULTIPLE ROWS
{
  $Name = str_replace(' | ', '', $Name); // THIS WORKS
  $Names = explode(" @ ", $Name); // @ FROM MySQL QUERY - ADDED TO MARK 
DIFFERENT FIELDS
  $Name = str_replace(' @ ', '', $Name); // THIS DOESN'T WORK
// var_dump($Names);

  for($i = 0, $l = count($array); $i < $l; ++$i) {
    $Name     = trim($Names[$i]);  
    $PAX      = trim($Names[$i]);
    $Location = trim($Names[$i]);     
  }
} else {    
   $Names = explode(" @ ", $Name);   
// var_dump($Names);
   $Name = trim($Names[0]);
   $PAX = trim($Names[1]);         
   $Location = trim($Names[2]);
}

   $Destination = strtoupper($row['Destination']);
   $ServiceType = strtoupper($row['ServiceType']);
   $TransferRef = $row['Coupon'];

print "<tr>
  <td bgcolor='$StatusHighlight' style='font-size:12px; text-
  align:center;'>$Ref</td>
  <td bgcolor='$StatusHighlight' style='font-size:12px; text-
  align:center;'>$TTime</td>
  <td bgcolor='$StatusHighlight' style='font-size:12px; text-
  align:center;'>$Location</td>
  <td bgcolor='$StatusHighlight' style='font-size:12px; text-
  align:center;'>$Destination</td>      
  <td bgcolor='$StatusHighlight' style='white-space: nowrap; font-size:12px; 
  text-align:right;'>$Name</td>     
  <td bgcolor='$StatusHighlight' style='font-size:12px; text-
  align:center;'>$PAX</td>
  <td bgcolor='$StatusHighlight' style='font-size:12px; text-
  align:center;'>$TransferRef</td>
</tr>";
$Location = ""; // WITHOUT THIS LAST ENTRY IS REPEATED
$Ref++;
} // END WHILE
```

The data is there, it's just not in the right place - any ideas? This is the output now:
[image]

Comment: Learned a lot since - like why you should never use GROUP_CONCAT ! ;-)

Comment: Luckily your thinking is moving in the right direction - but please stop using this deprecated API

Comment: LOL @ Strawberry - Now that is TRUE!

Comment: I have found the answer and will publish this weekend... I am currently testing live with real data... hint: I removed the array and added more MySQL GROUP_CONCAT calls..... well ok like Strawberry said... perhaps not the best method but it works and I am still open to a more programatic solution. Cheers.

Comment: One can admire the endeavour, but really this is a ridiculous way to manage issues of data display.

Comment: Here's an answer to annoy dissimilar problem I published earlier today - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43932940/angularjs-country-state-city-select-from-from-database/43934283#43934283

Comment: ...note, not a group_concat in sight

Comment: Yes, that is good work with arrays @Strawberry, I'll take an indepth look later today. Arrays are not my strong point but I do have the feeling that is the best way to go - arrays give full control over the data which is where GROUP_CONCAT seems to fail.