# two level joins in select query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have 3 tables: `posts`, `tags` and `post_tags`

in post_tags i store post tags! and a post can have many tags

Now i want to select all tag names of post 1 while selecting post's own columns.

posts columns are: `id`, `title`
tags columns are: `id`, `name`
post_tags columns are: `id`, `post_id`, `tag_id`

---

I have reached up to here, but this returns only one tag name for post, not all tags: (any ideas ?)

```
select 
     p.*, t.name as tag_name 
from 
     posts p 
     inner join posts_tags pt on p.id = pt.post_id 
     inner join tags t on pt.tag_id = t.id 
where 
     p.id = 1 limit 1
```

Comment: Looks good. Does it have more than one tag?

Comment: The `limit` wasn't there before.

Comment: Er, remove the limit.

Comment: That's fine. Just parse the result in PHP.

Comment: See for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43932940/angularjs-country-state-city-select-from-from-database/43934283#43934283 - but note that I'm not much of a PHP coder.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the tags on one row you can aggregate the results and use `group_concat()`:

```
select p.*, group_concat(t.name) as tag_name 
from posts p inner join
     posts_tags pt on p.id = pt.post_id inner joi
     tags t on pt.tag_id = t.id 
where p.id = 1
group by p.id;
```

This is the one time when it is safe to use `*` in the `select` with a `group by`, because `id` is unique in the table.  This usage is even condoned by the ANSI standard.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Select all posts with id=1 from posts_tags, each of them with the corresponding tags-details:

```
select 
     pt.id, // Optional
     pt.post_id, // Optional
     p.title,
     t.name as tag_name 
from 
    posts_tags as pt
    left join posts as p on p.id = pt.post_id
    left join tags as t on t.id = pt.tag_id
where 
     pt.post_id = 1
;
```

Comment: Yes, it seems to be the same (I don't have exercise with `inner join` anymore). But (please correct me if I'm mistaken) you are returning only one record by using the `LIMIT 1`. My sql statement returns all tags for the one post with id = 1.